# Value Matching Strings R

Tags: r

I have two large vectors (around 12 Mb each) in character format.

I would like to test which elements in `reallyLongVec` are also elements in `longVec`. To do so I use the `%in%` operator.

Doing:

```
any(reallyLongVec %in% longVec)
```

will return `FALSE`, which is not true because I know at least one element that occurs in both vectors.

Trying to fix this, I came up with this:

```
any(as.numeric(reallyLongVec) %in% as.numeric(longVec))
```

Which seems to work. However I still don't know why the first method fails and the second one comes up (allegedly) OK.

Added info about the vectors (that's a sample I have many of them):

```
str(reallyLongVec)
integer64 [1:1514487] NA NA 9420166506 9422343574 9442951711 9422188037 9421232760 9420999856 ...

str(longVec)
chr [1:82] "9420030876" "9420234791" "9420734998" "9421904327" "9422065425" "9422065599" "9422065763" "9422065938" "9422448407" "9422602821" "9423570399" "9423571512" ...
```

Comment: include head of the data or better add the output of `str(reallyLongVec)`

Comment: Added, probably the integer64 caused it.

Comment: `reallyLongVec` is of class `integer`, `longVec` is of class `character`. As `9420166506 != "9420166506"`, R will not match those. `any(reallyLongVec %in% as.numeric(longVec))` or `any(as.character(reallyLongVec) %in% longVec)` should both work.

Comment: @LAP Actually the first option `any(reallyLongVec %in% as.numeric(longVec))` won't work.

Comment: @MaorSH You are right, I didn't realize that `integer64` is a special, package-based class.